# Selenium Webdriver window switching fails randomly

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I am using InternetExplorerDriver (and I have to). I have two window handles. I have to switch mutliple times between these windows.
I do this using these two lines.

```
driver.switchTo().window(myWindowHandle1);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//body")).click();
```

I added the click on body because otherwise sometimes the switch did not work correctly and this worked for me fine ever since.

Now I have a new problem.
My third window switch (1. window1 -> window2; 2. window2 -> window1; 3. window1 -> window2;) does not work anymore.

```
ElementNotVisibleException: Cannot click on element --- in this case, line 2
```

So the body is not visible anymore. 
Previous window switches work perfectly, so the handles are correct.
Finding the body element By.tagName did not solve the problem.
Anyone had the same problem? Solutions?

Thanks in advance

Regards

Comment: Your xpath looks very abstract..There are 2 reasons while your switching fails occasionally. *Timeout* & Hidden Element. Try locating another element in window 3 by xpath..For example if your html code for this element is <input id='login' value='' text='enter username'> you can click on this element like this: `driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath=//input[contains(@id, 'login')]")).click();`

Comment: first of all, thanks, it worked. but still, why won't clicking on the body work? it does for all other window switches. the body is visible the whole time isn't it? and increasing timeouts also didn't help.

Comment: Clicking on the body element is not a great approach. The .click() method is documented to attempt to click at the center of the element. If the center of the element is not visible in the viewport, and cannot be scrolled into view, you may get the exception you're seeing, at least in the IE driver.

Comment: write an answer -> close the Q thx

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the answer,
I used the below method to switch to the new window,

```
public String switchwindow(String object, String data){
        try {

        String winHandleBefore = driver.getWindowHandle();

        for(String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()){
            driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);
        }
        }catch(Exception e){
        return Constants.KEYWORD_FAIL+ "Unable to Switch Window" + e.getMessage();
        }
        return Constants.KEYWORD_PASS;
        }
```

To move to parent window, i used the following code,

```
 public String switchwindowback(String object, String data){
            try {
                String winHandleBefore = driver.getWindowHandle();
                driver.close(); 
                //Switch back to original browser (first window)
                driver.switchTo().window(winHandleBefore);
                //continue with original browser (first window)
            }catch(Exception e){
            return Constants.KEYWORD_FAIL+ "Unable to Switch to main window" + e.getMessage();
            }
            return Constants.KEYWORD_PASS;
            }
```

Use this code to switch between the windows.